# How to query a percentage of values given a fixed value

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

Heres my latest conundrum:

I need to query a percentage customers within a given distance, where the Table CUSTOMERS has the columns CUST (Customer number), LOCX (distance +- value), LOCY(Distance +- value).

X will be my given distance.

Thus far I have:

```
SELECT CUST
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE
ABS (LOCX) <= X
AND
ABS (LOCY) <= X
```

This gives me the customers within X but still need the percentage value.

The resultant table will ideally include Distance (X), Number of Records, Total number of records,  and % of customers(%of records returned)

Comment: How about some example data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?  It uses conditional aggregation to get the number within X:

```
SELECT X,
       sum(case when abs(locx) <= x and abs(locy) <= x then 1 else 0 end) as NumWithinX,
       count(*) as Num,
       avg(case when abs(locx) <= x and abs(locy) <= x then 1.0 else 0 end) as RatioInX
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

EDIT:

In MySQL, you can do what you want as:

```
SELECT X,
       sum(abs(locx) <= x and abs(locy) <= x) as NumWithinX,
       count(*) as Num,
       concat(avg(abs(locx) <= x and abs(locy) <= x)*100, '%') as PercentInX
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

The `case` form also works (and is ANSI standard).  MySQL treats boolean values as `0` or `1`, so you can do direct arithmetic manipulations on them.

Comment: @user3178067 . . . To me, a value between 0 and 1 is more useful.  You can multiply by 100 and append a `'%'`, if you like.  The exact syntax for that depends on the database, and the question doesn't specify the database engine that you are using.

Comment: As an amateur, please accept my apologies for the lack of detail. I am using MySQL server, and PHPMyAdmin to conduct queries. I understand that a value between 0 and 1 is more useful, but I do have a mandatory percentage requirement. would you be kind enough to explain your statement of appending of a % please

Comment: The following is what I am after but there appears to be an error:

Comment: SELECT X AS DISTANCE,
       sum(case when abs(locx) <= X and abs(locy) <= X then 1 else 0 end) as QUANTITY,
       count(*) as TOTALRECORDS, (QUANTITY/TOTALRECORDS)*100 AS PERC
FROM CUSTOMER;

Comment: You cannot use column aliases at the same level of `select` where they are defined.  Look at my edited query.

Comment: Brillient, works a treat, thank you for your assistance